# Deploying an WPF application with Crystal Reports and SQL Server

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, deployment, crystal-reports

I have completed a WPF application in Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express. I have also used Crystal Reports in my project. Now I need to deploy the application on client's systems. I assume that I will have to install the following pre-requisites first.

1. .Net Framework 4.0
2. MS SQL Server 2008 express (which may require .Net 2.0)
3. CR Runtime for .Net 4.0
4. Report Viewer

IS there a way so that everything installs on its own? I have tried selecting all the above as ** prerequisites**, but that gives me an error that CR Runtime msi not found. Can I also include all the files within my software in the `bin folder`?
Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_1.msi from SAP website (google it) and place it in this location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports`

for .NET Framework 4.0\